# Process builder-Limit on Criteria Node

Tags: process-builder

Is there a limit on number of criteria nodes that we can use process builder.

Limit information on what I could find is: 
https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=process_limits.htm&language=en_US

Answer (score 3):

The limit of process builder criteria nodes is 200

Comment: Do you have a reference for this claim?

Comment: @AdrianLarson looks like the reference is in OP's link at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

As Idranath has provided the link on his question, it is stated from there that:

> Criteria nodes that are evaluated and actions that are executed at runtime per process: 2000

So the limit for criteria nodes defined on a process is 2000.